# Prove two sub-space is a direct sum of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

If we know a vector space V has a linear operator T from $V$ to itself. And this $T^2$ is an identity map. Then if we create two subspace $V+$ contains all $v$ such that $Tv=v$ and $V-$ contains all $Tv=-v$, now how to get those two subgroups are actually a direct sum of $V$?

To show their intersection only contain 0, we can quickly get that by contradiction. But how to get that all $v$ are in them. I tried to use contradiction again but don't get any progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $v\in V$

$$v = \frac{1}{2}\left(v-T(v)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(v+T(v)\right)$$

Then $\frac{1}{2}\left(v-T(v)\right) \in V_-$ and $\frac{1}{2}\left(v+T(v)\right)\in V_+$. You also should assume that characteristic of the field is $\neq 2$.

**Edit**

In case when the field is of characteristic $2$ there are counterexamples. Consider a linear endomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{F}_2^{\oplus 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2^{\oplus 2}$ with matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Then $\phi^2$ is the identity, but $\mathbb{F}_2^{\oplus 2}$ could not be decomposed on *plus* and *minus* part of $\phi$.